# Swift 3 - Apostrophes being converted to â on screen-scrape

Tags: html, swift, swift3, uiwebview

In my Swift 3 application, I am getting HTML text from a web api to render inside of a UIWebView.  However, apostrophes specifically and maybe other special characters are rendering as accent letters instead of their real value.  For example, the text for “Transportation’s” displays as “Transportationâs”.

The code is simple.

```
var myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
//myHTMLString = "some bâd string"
webview.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil);
```

The values are correct on the API.  Why is this happening when grabbing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the encoding to `.utf8`

I'm not sure why the `.ascii` isn't working, though I suspect it has to do with HTML entity encoding. If I find a reason, I'll update this answer...

*Update*: This [w3schools.com page](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp) explains that HTML is now considered UTF-8 standard. UTF-8 can handle a larger set of characters. Apparently the webview browser understands HTML entities (for example, `&apos;` representing an apostrophe) in UTF-8, but not ASCII.